# Django 1.7 - inserting model data using bulk_create and then saving

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a custom method in a migration file that creates a list of model objects (with values derived from a list of matching JSON objects) and uses `bulk_create` to insert this list into the model.  The code looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

def populate_db( apps, schema_editor ):

    mymodel = apps.get_model( 'myapp', 'mymodel' )
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    mymodel_objs = [<obj1>,<obj2>,...,<objn>]
    mymodel.objects.using( db_alias ).bulk_create( mymodel_objs )
    mymodel.save()
```

But I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
mymodel.save()
TypeError: unbound method save() must be called with mymodel instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

The docs say that `bulk_create` does not save data to the db, how else is it possible to do this, using only one query, which is the supposed advantage of `bulk_create`?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `bulk_create` doesn't save the data? It is specifically meant to save multiple objects at a time. It doesn't call any custom `save` method, but it _does_ save the data. Anyway, `mymodel` in this case is a model class, not an instance, and `save` is an instance method. You can't call instance methods without an instance.

Comment: In the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/ it says that `save()` is not called when using `bulk_create`, so does this mean `bulk_create` writes to the db without instantiating a model?  Sorry I'm new to Django and the Django docs are not clear on this.

Comment: it means that instead of calling save() for each instance, django creates one sql statement that inserts all entities and executes it

Comment: I was also confused by the way this is written in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bulk_create **does** save  data to the database. The caveat with save() means that model's save method is not called for each instance, so if you have overriden the model's save method with any special logic, it will not be executed. In your case you can just remove the Model.save() line